# Finding employee from workbook #1 listed in workbook #2 and highlighting the employees not listed in both workbooks.

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 different excel workbooks. workbook #1 has first and last name of an employee. Workbook #2 has first initial and last name of an employee. How can I see if all employees listed in one workbook appear in the other workbook? And I need it to highlight the employees who only appear in the 1 workbook and not the other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Excel too well, and I am sure there is a better solution. But I'm pretty sure mine will work.

First, in your first workbook, we will rename people to follow the same format as workbook 2.

Joe Smith -> J Smith

You can do this by splitting your "Joe Smith" column at the space to be "Joe" in one column, and "Smith" in the next. Then you can call the concatenate function:

=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1), " ",A1)

To take the first letter of the first column, add a space, and add the entire last name.

Now you have two workbooks with identical names. You can do a vlookup to search for employees. And you can highlight the ones that exist. The ones that don't - well those are left out.